# change javascript object's method on the fly

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript object called Button. This is an object on a HTML5 canvas, and changes it's color when the mouse enters it:

```
Button.prototype.handleMouseMove = function() {
    if(this.isMouseOver() && !this.mouseIsOver) {this.onMouseIn(); this.mouseIsOver = true;}
    if(!this.isMouseOver() && this.mouseIsOver) {this.onMouseOut(); this.mouseIsOver = false;}
}

Button.prototype.onMouseIn = function() {
    this.setColor("red");
}
```

I'd like to change onMouseIn method on the fly,but I don't really know how to do it.

I've tried:

```
button1.onMouseIn = button1.setColor("xy");
```

and

```
Button.prototype.changeMouseInAction(fn) {
    this.onMouseIn = fn;
}
button1.changeMouseInAction(button1.setColor("xy"));
```

but nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :-

```
  button1.onMouseIn = function(){
                         button1.setColor("xy");
                      }
```